# Вопросы с хвостиками / Paзделительные вопросы

Tags: грамотная-речь

При переводе с английского языка является ли нормой оставлять в конце предложения короткий вопрос?

> Вы говорите по-английски, не так ли?
>
> Это же не связано со мной... так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормой при переводе является то, как передаётся тот же смысл в языке, на который вы переводите, насколько типично получаемое выражение для той же ситуации. В интересах передачи смысла и подходящего к ситуации стиля грамматические формы могут быть выбраны другими. Для первого примера может подойти менее формальное, ненавязчивое выражение:

> Вы ведь говорите по-английски?

Для второго примера нужно знать исходный вариант - что там в вопросе (OK? Right? Yeah?)

Comment: Там Right .....

Comment: Скорее всего, вопрос в конце понадобится, а какой именно, зависит от отношений между собеседниками, напр. более дружественно звучит: "Верно?", "Так ведь?", "Согласен?".